# Distance between matrices with perturb eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

I have two matrices A,B with eigenvectors $v_1(A),..,v_n(A)$ and $v_1(B),..,v_n(B)$ such that for all i $||(v_i(A)-v_i(B))||<\epsilon$.

Can I give a non-trivial bound for $||A-B||$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Some initial steps that you might find helpful:

I assume that $\|\cdot\|$ refers to the Euclidean vector norm and the spectral norm for matrices.

First of all, we consider the case where $\lambda_i(A) = \lambda_i(B) =: \lambda_i$. Let $P_A$ denote the matrix with columns $v_1(A),\dots,v_n(A)$ and define $P_B$ similarly. Let $\Lambda$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$. Let $I$ denote the identity matrix. We note that $\|P_A - P_B\| \leq n \epsilon,$ and
$$
\|P_A^{-1} - P_B^{-1}\| = \|P_A^{-1}(P_B - P_A)P_B^{-1}\| \leq \|P_A^{-1}\| \cdot \|P_B^{-1}\| \cdot \|P_A - P_B\|.
$$

From there, we have
\begin{align}
\|A - B\| &= \|P_A\Lambda P_A^{-1} - P_B\Lambda P_B^{-1}\|
\\ & \leq \|(P_A\Lambda P_A^{-1} - P_B\Lambda P_A^{-1})\| + \|(P_B\Lambda P_A^{-1} - P_B\Lambda P_B^{-1})\|
\\ & =\|(P_A - P_B)\Lambda P_A^{-1}\| + 
\|P_B\Lambda(P_A^{-1} - P_B^{-1})\|
\\ & \leq 
\|P_A - P_B\| \cdot \|\Lambda\| \cdot \|P_A^{-1}\| + 
\|P_B\|\cdot \|\Lambda\| \cdot \|P_A^{-1} - P_B^{-1}\|
\\ & \leq 
\|P_A - P_B\| \cdot \|\Lambda\| \cdot \|P_A^{-1}\| + 
\|P_A - P_B\|\cdot \|\Lambda\|\cdot \|P_A^{-1}\| \cdot \|P_B^{-1}\|\cdot \|P_B\| 
\\ & = \|P_A - P_B\| \cdot \|\Lambda\| \cdot \|P_A^{-1}\|(1 + \|P_B^{-1}\|\cdot \|P_B\|)
\\ & =  \epsilon n  \|\Lambda\| \cdot \|P_A^{-1}\|(1 + \kappa(P_B)),
\end{align}
where $\kappa(M)$ denotes the condition number of $M$.

From there, I'd look for an upper bound to $\kappa(P_B)$ in terms of $\kappa(P_A)$ and $\epsilon$.